# How hashmap behaves in below scenario?

Tags: java

Please find below code.

```
Map<Long,String> unsortMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
unsortMap.put(new Long(123), "a");
unsortMap.put(new Long(123), "ab");
```

In above case map stores only **123** and **ab**. my understanding is key-value pairs are stored in buckets. each bucket will have unique number and is decided by key's hashcode. in above code as both keys hashcodes are different, how does hashmap behaves internally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of `Long` the `hashCode` method is overriden to return the same value if the numeric values are the same. In fact, looking inside the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Long.java.html), the method is this:

```
public int hashCode() {
   return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
}
```

Comment: Hi Tudor, Thanks for your reply. here i am creating two new objects. so each object's hashcode(memory location) is different. i mean i am thinking that two different objects are created on heap. please clarify me.

Comment: Yes, but when Hashmap will calculate the hashkey it will be same.. so it will replace the old one

Comment: The Long class overrides the `hashCode()` method. It does not return the memory location of the reference.

Comment: @user1016403: Indeed, they are different objects in memory, but the `hashCode` method inherited from `Object` is overriden (see the source code I posted). Thus you can see from above that if the values are equal the hash code will also be equal.

Comment: @user1016403 you are right about their memory location being distinct, but only the default implementation of hashcode returns the memory location; almost any key candidate to a hash based collection should override that method or "equal" object retrieval would be complicated.

Comment: @Scorpion, is bucket number calculated based on key? or simply memeory location is considered as bucket number? Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403: I just showed you how the bucket number is calculated for `Long` objects. See the code I posted.

Comment: @user1016403, the bucket number is calculated using the object's `hashCode()` method, which (for `Long`, and for many classes) is not dependent on the object's location in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code below, you will see the hascode is the same for your 2 longs, although they are different instances (references are not equal):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long a = new Long(123);
    Long b = new Long(123);
    System.out.println(a.hashCode()); //123
    System.out.println(b.hashCode()); //123
    System.out.println(a == b); //false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hashcode is not different for identical long values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode%28%29) :

> exclusive OR of the two halves of the primitive long value held by
>   this Long object. That is, the hashcode is the value of the
>   expression:
>
> (int)(this.longValue()^(this.longValue()>>>32))

Answer (score 0):

In hashmap key must be unique on whole map. If you are inserting different value for same key, then HashMap will override with newly value.